# How can i convert JObject to object in C#?

Tags: c#, json, type-conversion

I have a JObject such as :

```
JObject obj = new JObject();
obj.Add(new JProperty("Name","Olivier"));
obj.Add(new JProperty("Surname","Big"));
obj.Add(new JProperty("FatherName","Johnatan"));
```

I want to convert obj above to object

If I use the this code below

```
var result1 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(obj.ToString());
```

the result is like this
[image: Img1]

But the result that wanted is like below

```
var TheResultIWant = new { Name = "Olivier", Surname = "Big", FatherName = "Johnatan" };
```

[image: Img2]

Is there any kind of way I can obtain the object like the second image. I cannot code like it because I don't know the property name.

Comment: i have same problem as well.

Comment: A JObject *is* an object already. It's a dynamic object too, which means you can already use it the way you'd use an anonymous type. If you want to deserialize a *JSON string* to a specific type, pass the type to `DeserializeObject`. You can't deserialize to an anonymous type

Comment: If you use `dynamic TheResultIWant = obj;` you can retrieve properties by name, eg `var name=TheResultIWant.Name;`

Comment: BTW post the code in the question itself, not links to images of the code. Images can't be copied, compiled, googled or compared

Comment: Also it would be helpful if you explain why do you need it to work this way and what is the code that is using the object.

Comment: `i dont know the property name.` then you can't use anonymous types. What *do* you know, and how are you trying to use that object? If you don't know the property, how will you retrieve it?

Comment: CustomContext d = new CustomContext();       

            List<ReportField> myList = d.ReportFields.ToList();            

            JObject obj = new JObject();
            foreach (var item in myList)
            {
                obj.Add(new JProperty(item.PropertName, item.PropertyValue));
            }


            var result1 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(obj.ToString());

            var TheResultIWant = new { Name = "Olivier", Surname = "Big", FatherName = "Johnatan" };

Comment: I am creating a json object with the value from the database. this json object is not working for me. I need a code that will produce the result in picture 2.

Comment: Edit the question and add what you want there. The pictures don't explain anything. If you don't know the properties, you can't use anonymous types. If you want to handle arbitrary properties, just use `JObject` as is. That's what it's for

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could use method `DeserializeAnonymousType` for that:

```
    JObject obj = new JObject();
    obj.Add(new JProperty("Name", "Olivier"));
    obj.Add(new JProperty("Surname", "Big"));
    obj.Add(new JProperty("FatherName", "Johnatan"));

    var result = new
    {
        Name = "",
        Surname = "",
        FatherName = ""
    };
    result  = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(obj.ToString(), result);
```

Another option is to use `dynamic` and third option which is by far most used is to create your own type and use it:

```
public class Person 
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   ...
}

Person result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(obj.ToString());
```

Comment: I don't know the anonymous type. properties of type come from database. I need to create an object with the incoming properties. giving result as in picture 2

Comment: @NSkao that's not what you asked in the question though. What is the *real* problem? And if you don't know the type, why not use JObject as-is?

Comment: Yeah, that would be *another* question. In your example in Img2 you see anonymous object with 3 properties.

Comment: I want to get result 2 when I render JObject.

Comment: @NSkao there's no render code there. What you posted is an anonymous type. To create an anonymous type you need to know what properties to include in the first place

Comment: An anonymous type is still a type, it has to be compiled, the Newtonsoft library doesn't create custom types like that, it can fill instances of existing types, but it doesn't create custom types. In which context would you use the resulting type anyway?

Answer (score 3):

A JObject is an already deserialized object. It can be used as [a dynamic object](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonDynamic.htm) so there's no need to serialize to a string and get back another object.

```
dynamic TheResultIWant = obj; 
var name=TheResultIWant.Name;
```

It's already possible to access properties by key, like a dictionary:

```
var name=obj["Name"];
```

This returns a JToken. If the type of the value is known, [Value< T>](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Value__1.htm) or `Values<T>` can be used to retrieve it:

```
var name=obj["Name"].Value<string>();
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. I used to do it this way but forgot how I did it. There's no need to deserialize anything.

Comment: only issue with that it appears Value<> can't return any non-premitive type